# How to update json file sorted by number? - Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

For example I have a JSON file with a mess number

```
{
    "data": {
        "31": {
           ...

        },
        "52": {
           ...
        },
        "1": {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to make It like sorted by number so the json data will not be messed up

```
{
    "data": {
        "52": {
           ...

        },
        "31": {
           ...
        },
        "52": {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a code that uses:

```
with open ("file.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    file = json.load(f)

file["data"].update(
    {num: {"question": question, "answer": answer, "options": options}}
)
```

My errors code: `TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence`

Answer (score 0):

#### Option #1

Use `sorted` with `key` argument:

```py
import json

my_dict = {
    "data": {
        "31": {
           "k": "..."
        },
        "52": {
           "k": "..."
        },
        "1": {
           "k": "..."
        }
    }
}

my_dict['data'] = dict(sorted(my_dict['data'].items(), key=lambda t: int(t[0])))
print(my_dict['data'])
```

Result:

```
{'1': {'k': '...'}, '31': {'k': '...'}, '52': {'k': '...'}}
```

#### Option #2

Use `json.dumps` with `sort_keys` argument:

```py
print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "1": {
      "k": "..."
    },
    "31": {
      "k": "..."
    },
    "52": {
      "k": "..."
    }
  }
}
```